# How to find max values from multiple lists?

Tags: python, performance, list, numpy, max

I have multiple lists (or numpy arrays) of the same size and I want to return an array of the same size with the max value at each point.

For example,

```
A = [[0,1,0,0,3,0],[1,0,0,2,0,3]]
B = [[1,0,0,0,0,4],[0,5,6,0,1,1]]
C = numpy.zeros_like(A)
for i in xrange(len(A)):
    for j in xrange(len(A[0])):
        C[i][j] = max(A[i][j],B[i][j])
```

The result is `C` = `[[1,1,0,0,3,4],[1,5,6,2,1,3]]`

This works fine, but is not very efficient - especially for the size of arrays that I have and the number of arrays I need to compare. How can I do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 8):

Use [`numpy.maximum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html):

> `numpy.maximum(x1, x2[, out])`
>  Element-wise maximum of array
>   elements.
>
> Compare two arrays and returns a new array containing the element-wise
>   maxima. If one of the elements being compared is a nan, then that
>   element is returned. If both elements are nans then the first is
>   returned. The latter distinction is important for complex nans, which
>   are defined as at least one of the real or imaginary parts being a
>   nan. The net effect is that nans are propagated.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not sure how I overlooked that function.

Comment: and if you need more than 2 arguments, numpy.maximum.reduce([x1,x2,x3...])

Answer (score 5):

A non Numpy Solution

```
>>> [map(max,a,b,c) for a,b,c in zip(A,B,C)]
[[1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 4], [1, 5, 6, 2, 1, 3]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you needed to compare more that 2 arrays you could do the following

```
from numpy import random, dstack

A = random.random((2,5))
B = random.random((2,5))
C = random.random((2,5))

stacked_arrays = dstack((A,B,C))
max_of_stack = stacked_arrays.max(2)
```

[dstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) will turn your 2D arrays into a 3D stack of 2D arrays

The 2 inside of the parenthesis of `max` performs the maximum operation along the 3rd axis which is the new axis which `dstack` has created for us

This will scale to any number of 2D arrays of the same size

Comment: this is a great option!

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
numpy_arrays = [A, B, C]

result = [max(elem) for elem in zip(*numpy_arrays)]
```

?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to unpack `elem` in `max`. Downvote is not me.

Comment: Indeed, it is not - max and min works with either multile arguments or a sequence -