# Map and max two lists

Tags: python, list, max

I am trying to find the biggest list, in place, by comparing two lists. I'm trying to use map and max, but it seems like they're not working as I want them to.

```
l = [0,1]
l2 = [1,0]
list(map(max, l, l2)))

[1,1]
```

and looks like 'get me the biggest values from these two lists' while I'm trying to compute: 'compare each element, and give me the list with the most biggest values', in this case, l2 would be the biggest.

Comment: [`np.maximum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) is built for that but can you use `numpy`?

Comment: I was trying to accomplish this by not incorporating any other libs.

Comment: What are your expected input and output? what happens if they tie?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find max values from multiple lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129561/how-to-find-max-values-from-multiple-lists)

Comment: "give me the list with the most biggest values" - what exactly do you mean by that? Both lists contain a 1, which is the biggest value, so why should `l2` be the "biggest"?

Comment: is it possible that you have miswritten `l2`? maybe it was something like `l2=[4,0]` and you are searching for the list with the biggest difference among their elements? This is the only thing I can think of

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop:

```
l = [0,1]
l2 = [1,0]

res = []

for i in range(0,len(l)):
   res.append(max(l[i], l2[i]))
```

Comment: Simplified: `res = [max(i, i2) for i, i2 in zip(l, l2)]`

Comment: Sure, it is more pythonic!

Comment: @wjandrea Still incorrect. I want to get the maximum list, out of two lists, not the sum of the maximum lists combined. :/

Comment: @OktayGardener Oh I'm just simplifying the method, not saying it's correct. In fact your question isn't clear enough to say if it's correct.