# How to find max values from multiple list and the corresponding list it came from

Tags: python, max, elementwise-operations

So I have n arrays which I want to do a element-wise comparisent and find the max value with python. A good solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129561/how-to-find-max-values-from-multiple-lists) is:

`np.maximum.reduce([a,b,c])`.

But I would like to have another list with tuples corresponding to the max value and the list from which it came from. Say e.g.

`a = [1, 7, 3]`,
`b = [5, 3, 6]`,
`c = [3, 5, 4]`

`np.maximum.reduce([a,b,c])` will return a list  `[5,7,6]` which is fine.

But I would like another list:

`[(5,"b"), (7, "a"), (6,"b")]`

Comment: In your example answer you have B twice, is this on purpose? Why do you want the strings "a", "b" in your list of tuples?

Comment: Yes its on purpose. I dont per se want the strings but rather return the list from which the max value came from.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1, 7, 3]
b = [5, 3, 6]
c = [3, 5, 4]
l = {
    "a": a,
    "b": b,
    "c": c
}
k = list(l.keys())
transposed = list(map(list, zip(*l.values())))
max_indexes = [x.index(max(x)) for x in transposed]
column_max_with_keys = [(x[i], k[i]) for i, x in zip(max_indexes, transposed)]
```

Result:

```
[(5, 'b'), (7, 'a'), (6, 'b')]
```

Comment: This answer is clean

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform source dictionary into a nested list of value and key and apply [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) to find maximum from values on same index.

Initial transformation can be done using next list comprehension:

```py
[[(i, k) for i in v] for k, v in l.items()]
```

Then we can use various options to iterate over inner lists together. First option will be to unpack them into [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and use another list comprehension to call max on each group:

```py
[max(i) for i in zip(*([(i, k) for i in v] for k, v in l.items()))]
```

Another option will be to exploit ability of [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to process multiple iterables and unpack lists there:

```py
list(map(max, *([(i, k) for i in v] for k, v in l.items())))
```

Full code:

```py
l = {
    "a": [1, 7, 3],
    "b": [5, 3, 6],
    "c": [3, 5, 4]
}
result = [max(i) for i in zip(*([(i, k) for i in v] for k, v in l.items()))]
# OR
result = list(map(max, *([(i, k) for i in v] for k, v in l.items())))
```

Output:

```py
[(5, 'b'), (7, 'a'), (6, 'b')]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I dont per se want the strings but rather return the list from which the max value came from.

Given this distinction by OP, I made this snippet of code:

```
a = [1, 7, 3]
b = [5, 3, 6]
c = [3, 5, 4]

def find_maxes(*args):

    return_data = list()
    
    for arg in args:
        return_data.append((max(arg), arg))
    
    return return_data
        

ret_1 = find_maxes(a, b, c)
ret_2 = find_maxes(a, b)
ret_3 = find_maxes(a)

print(f"Return 1:\n{ret_1}")  # [(7, [1, 7, 3]), (6, [5, 3, 6]), (5, [3, 5, 4])]
print(f"Return 2:\n{ret_2}")  # [(7, [1, 7, 3]), (6, [5, 3, 6])]
print(f"Return 3:\n{ret_3}")  # [(7, [1, 7, 3])]
```

This function takes in any number of lists and finds the maximum value in the list. It then adds a tuple of length 2 to the return_data list. Each tuple in the list is in the format:

(max_value, list_searched)

Where max_value is the maximum value found in list_searched.